# Linux foo-over-udp tunnel creation issues

Tags: linux, linux-networking, kernel, udp, tunnel

I want to create [fou](https://lwn.net/Articles/614348/)(foo-over-udp) tunnel on linux 4.4.10 using iproute2 4.5.0 and while trying to create a tunnel i get the following error:

```
sudo ip link add dev tun0 type ipip remote 172.19.0.9 local 172.19.0.8 encap fou encap-sport auto encap-dport 4444
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

While this usually indicates, that i provided wrong arguments, device still gets created with a wierd name and unconfigured:

```
10: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT
group default qlen 1
     link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

I should also mention that fou and ipip kernel modules are loaded:

```
fou                     9093  0
ip6_udp_tunnel          1967  1 fou
udp_tunnel              2547  1 fou
ipip                    5260  0
ip_tunnel              13315  1 ipip
tunnel4                 2389  1 ipip
```

I didn't try with any other kernel version, but i did try with latest version of iproute2. I should also mention that i was trying this setup in linux network namespace, but i get the same problem if i do it outside of the namespace. What could be causing this issue, and is there any other alternative to configure fou tunnel? By my observations iproute2 is problematic one.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to setup a FOU tunnel between two virtual machines on the same LAN running unmodified ubuntu 16.04.01. They started with the following configuration network-wise:

```
jeff@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~$ ip addr show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo

   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 ::1/128 scope host 

   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:97:1d:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 192.168.1.137/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3

   valid_lft 86358sec preferred_lft 86358sec

inet6 fe80::3675:b335:4de3:9d6c/64 scope link 

   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

jeff@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~$ 

jeff@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16-2:~$ ip addr show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo

   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

inet6 ::1/128 scope host 

   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast
 state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:40:13:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

inet 192.168.1.135/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3

   valid_lft 86352sec preferred_lft 86352sec

inet6 fe80::7086:fe13:ab8:b44f/64 scope link 

   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I then ran the following to configure both VMs in a 10-net using a FOU tunnel:

```
root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~# modprobe fou

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~# ip fou add port 55137 ipproto 4

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~# ip link add name fou0 type ipip remote 192.168.1.135 local 192.168.1.137 encap fou encap-sport 55137 encap-dport 55135 dev enp0s3

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~# ip link set up dev tunl0

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~# ip link set up dev fou0

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~# ip addr add 10.0.0.137/24 dev fou0

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16:~#


root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16-2:~# modprobe fou

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16-2:~# ip fou add port 55135 ipproto 4

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16-2:~# ip link add name fou0 type ipip remote 192.168.1.137 local 192.168.1.135 encap fou encap-sport 55135 encap-dport 55137 dev enp0s3

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16-2:~# ip link set up dev tunl0

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16-2:~# ip link set up dev fou0

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16-2:~# ip addr add 10.0.0.135/24 dev fou0

root@jeff-VirtualBox-ubuntu-16-2:~#
```

It worked fine for me. Your mileage may vary. 8^)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have CONFIG_NET_FOU_IP_TUNNELS enabled and rebuild the the kernel if not, with the this configuration.

Following command works for me.
ip link add name fou-ipip type ipip remote 192.168.1.2 local 192.168.1.1 encap fou encap-sport auto encap-dport 6635

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the command has this format, which does not match yours:

ip link add name {name} type ipip ...

In general, nothing is "created with a weird name", i.e., created with a name which is a sequence of characters (in this case, "tunl0") which does not appear in the software's input.  So it's very likely that the tunl0 device is entirely unrelated to your actions; it probably was there before.  Also, it suggests using a different name for the device you're trying to create, to reduce confusion regarding status reports.

Answer (score 0):

> While this usually indicates, that i provided wrong arguments, device
> still gets created with a wierd name and unconfigured

`tunl0` is default `ipip` device and created automatically when `ipip` kernel module is loaded. It's loaded automatically when you execute your command even if it's failed. You cannot get rid of that device if you're using `ipip` tunneling, you can either configure it or leave unconfigured. In case you do not use `ipip` anymore, just unload the module by `modprobe -r ipip` to get rid of it.

> RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

It may indicate that some options is not supported by your kernel or `ip`.

I'll quote IPIP over FOU tunnel creation instruction from [ipipou](https://github.com/netprickle/ipipou/#when-ipipou-is-useless) repo. It's comprehensive enough so includes your case too, worth to try, just substitute example values to yours.

**on server side**:

```
# Load FOU kernel module
modprobe fou

# Create IPIP tunnel encapsulated to FOU,
# ipip kernel module will be loaded automatically.
ip link add name ipipou0 type ipip \
    remote 198.51.100.2 local 203.0.113.1 \
    encap fou encap-sport 10000 encap-dport 20001 \
    mode ipip dev eth0

# Add FOU listener for this tunnel
ip fou add port 10000 ipproto 4 local 203.0.113.1 dev eth0

# Assign IP address to the tunnel
ip address add 172.28.0.0 peer 172.28.0.1 dev ipipou0

# Up tunnel
ip link set ipipou0 up
```

**on client side** (the client can be behind NAT):

```
modprobe fou

ip link add name ipipou1 type ipip \
    remote 203.0.113.1 local 192.168.0.2 \
    encap fou encap-sport 10001 encap-dport 10000 encap-csum \
    mode ipip dev eth0

# Options "local", "peer", "peer_port", "dev" can be not supported
# by old kernels and can be skipped.
ip fou add port 10001 ipproto 4 \
    local 192.168.0.2 peer 203.0.113.1 peer_port 10000 dev eth0

ip address add 172.28.0.1 peer 172.28.0.0 dev ipipou1

ip link set ipipou1 up
```

**where**:

- `ipipou*` — tunnel interface name
- `203.0.113.1` — server public IP
- `198.51.100.2` — client public IP
- `192.168.0.2` — client IP assigned to `eth0`
- `10001` — client local FOU port
- `20001` — client public FOU port
- `10000` — server public FOU port
- `encap-csum` — an option to add checksum to inner UDP packets; can be replaced with `noencap-csum` to avoid calculation and keep it empty, packets integrity will be controlled by outer UDP layer (while the packet is in the tunnel).
- `eth0` — local base interface for the tunnel
- `172.28.0.1` — tunnel client private IP address
- `172.28.0.0` — tunnel server private IP address

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on Raspberry Pi. I tried the same 'ip link' command on PC Ubuntsu and it worked.

The reason seems to be the CONFIG_NET_FOU_IP_TUNNELS which Vijaya commented.

PC Ubuntsu:

```
$ lsmod | grep fou
fou                    28672  0
ip6_udp_tunnel         16384  1 fou
udp_tunnel             16384  1 fou
ip_tunnel              24576  3 fou,ipip,ip_gre
```

Raspberry Pi:

```
$ lsmod | grep tunnel
ip6_udp_tunnel         16384  1 fou
udp_tunnel             28672  1 fou
ip_tunnel              32768  1 ip_gre
```

Note that the ip_tunnel mod is not used by fou on Raspberry Pi. It seems I need to build kernel module by myself.